# laravel login via ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to do the login in laravel via ajax so I want this function to return only json object in case of errors 
the function returns json only when a input (email or password is empty) , but I insert wrong data in bought of theme the function returns a html page with errors include; but I want to return only these errors without html page (I assume that it it dose `return response()->back()->withErrors('errors')` )

my Js code :

```
$('#form-login').submit(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
        event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening             
        var data = {
            email : $('#login_email').val(),
            password : $('#login_password').val(),
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/login',
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                if (jqXHR.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').includes('json')) {

                        window.location.reload();

                    }
            },
            error:function(data) {
                // console.log(data['email'])
                // console.log(data.email)
                if(data.responseJSON.email){
                        $('#Email-help-block').html(data.responseJSON.email[0]) 
                    }else{
                        $('#Email-help-block').html('')
                    }
                if(data.responseJSON.password){
                        $('#Password-help-block').html(data.responseJSON.password[0]) 
                    }else{
                        $('#Password-help-block').html('')
                    }
            },
        })


    });
```

the function login :

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request); // this is where it returns errors
    // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
    // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
    $throttles = $this->isUsingThrottlesLoginsTrait();

    if ($throttles && $lockedOut = $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return $this->handleUserWasAuthenticated($request, $throttles);
    }

    // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
    // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
    // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
    if ($throttles && ! $lockedOut) {
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
    }

    return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem is:

```
<body>
    <main class="container small">
        <div class="middle">
         <body>
    <main class="container small">
        <div class="middle">
            <img 
            <br>
            <div class="error valign-wrapper" style=" border: 2px solid red; border-radius: 7px;" hidden>
                <h5 class="center-align"> Helaas zijn uw inloggegevens incorrect </h5>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="/api/v1/login" class="login">
                 {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <input type="text" name="email" class="emailaddress" placeholder="Je e-mailadres..." style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                <input type="password" name="password" class="password" placeholder="Je wachtwoord..." style="background-image: url(&quot;data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVR4nGP6zwAAAgcBApocMXEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=&quot;); cursor: auto;" autocomplete="off">
                <div class="left">
                    <a href="/password/reset">Wachtwoord vergeten?</a>
                    <a href="/">← Terug</a>
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Log in">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
@include('footer')
@push('scripts')
    <script>
    $('form.login').submit(function(e) {
        $form = $(this);
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(window.location.origin + $form.attr('action'), $form.serialize())
        .done(function(data) {
            window.location.href = 'account';
        })
        .fail(function() {
            $('.error').show();
        });
    });
    </script>
@endpush
```

This is html with the error hidden (or you could show it with just ajax) on error. My javascript is pushed to a javascript stack at the bottom.